# Simulating location of the moon

Tags: the-moon, photography

I'm researching high altitude photography and want to know a schedule for taking pictures of the moon.

Preferably I want a picture of the (full) moon on the horizon.

How would I go about scheduling such an event from a high altitude location?

Comment: Planetarium software like Sellarium would be your best bet, so you can actually visuallize what the moon will look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The US Naval Observatory has a [web page](https://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/RS_OneYear) which lets you print a table of moonrise/moonset times for any location, together with twilight times. If you use this approach, you would print the data and then examine it for a suitable date. I don't know of a computing resource where you would put in your requirements it would report the appropriate date and time.

Comment: Turns out they have several data sources that I can cross reference.  Unfortunately this doesn't allow for altitude input in it's calculations but I think I can manage.

Answer (score 2):

The Isaac Newton Group of Telescopes has a web resource for plotting the altitude of celestial bodies, given a date and your latitude, longitude, altitude, etc. It is used for general RA, Dec. angles, but it automatically plots the altitude of the moon as well, for any plot that you generate. It's called [Staralt](http://catserver.ing.iac.es/staralt/).

Comment: This is very useful, I'm still learning how to read the data but I think it will help verify my plans.